# how to check for multiple instances of the same element in a list?

Tags: python

SOLVED: Zulfiqaar's solution in the comments worked with a bit of tweaking to the rest of the code

> if you are entering "abcd" as an input, turn it into a list of individual characters by list("abcd") which you can then compare elementwise eg [char for char in split_list if char in correct_letters]

So, I've been trying to make a rudimentary hangman game in python, but I've run into a roadblock when comparing the letters in the list with the inputted letters.  The game doesn't recognise if the letters inputted are correct if you enter more than one, and instead it penalises you as if you entered a wrong letter.  Is there a way to fix this?

The code in question is:

```
loop3 = True
while loop3 == True:
    print(guessWord)
    letterGuess = str(input("\nGuess letter or word\n\n"))
    if letterGuess.upper() == word:
        loop2 = 0
        loop3 = 0
    elif letterGuess.isalpha() == False:
        print("\nneed letter or word\n\n")
    elif len(letterGuess) != 1:
        print("\none letter or word\n\n")
    else:
        letterGuess = letterGuess.upper()
        loop3 = False
```

Edit: I thought this was implied, but the lists are further back in the code, here they are:

```
loop1 = True
while loop1 == True:
    hangmanWord = str(input("What word?\n\n"))
    if hangmanWord.isalpha() == False:
        print("need letter")
    else:
        loop1 = False
```

Which goes on to:

```
word = hangmanWord.upper()
wordLetters = list(word)
```

and:

```
for letter in hangmanWord:
    guessWord.append("_")
```

Comment: *"comparing the letters in the list"* I don't see any lists.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are no lists, no comparison. Please provide a sample I/O

Comment: if you are entering `"abcd"` as an input, turn it into a list of individual characters by `list("abcd")` which you can then compare elementwise eg `[char for char in split_list if char in correct_letters]`

Comment: @Zulfiqaar: I don't get it, we can iterate through `str` objects, no need in conversion to `list`